# Modal doesn't pop out when click on image link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I am trying to pop up a modal by clicking on an image link, but for some reason it doesn't work.
Here is my HTML code:

```
 <div id="imagesMain">
         <div class="imagebox">
            <img src="c://images/summer.jpg">
             <div class="caption">Estate in Giappone<h1>Tradizione e fascino 
 del Giappone rurale</h1></div>             
         </div>
         <div class="imagebox">
            <img src="c://images/fall.jpg">
             <div class="caption">Autunno in Giappone<h1>Foglie rosse e 
    giardini incantati </h1></div>             
         </div>
         <div class="imagebox">
            <img src="c://images/winter.jpg">
             <div class="caption">Inverno in Giappone<h1>La neve ed il 
 tepore degli onsen </h1></div>             
         </div>
         <div class="imagebox">
             <a href="#openmodal"><img src="c://images/spring.jpg"></a>
             <div class="caption">Primavera in Giappone<h1>Seguendo il 
 sakura tra templi e castelli</h1></div>             
         </div>

            <div id="openmodal" class="modaldialog">
    <div>
<a href="#close" title="Chiudi" class="close">X</a>
<h2>Sakura nel Tohoku</h2>
<table id="customers">
    <tr>
    <th>Giorno</th>
        <th>Percorso</th>
        <th>Pernottamento</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Giorno 1</td>
        <td>TOKYO/AOMORI/HINOSAKI</td>
        <td>Art Hotel Hirosaki City</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>6:00</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify; width: 
60%;">text</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Giorno 2</td>
        <td>HIROSAKI/KAKUNODATE</td>
        <td>Hotel Folkloro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>9:00</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify; width: 
 60%;">text</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Giorno 2</td>
        <td>KAKUNODATE/MORIOKA/TOKYO</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>9:30</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; text-align: justify; width: 
60%;">text</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.modaldialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
width: 650px;
position: relative;
margin: 1% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
background: #606061;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }

#customers {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}



#customers td, #customers th {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}
```

If I run the code on stand alone (separate page, only one image) it works perfectly. 
Is there anybody that can kindly help me to fix this bug?
Thank you very much in advance,
Cheers
Valter

Comment: Can you post a working example(The one that you mentioned as "stand alone") on jsfiddle or codpen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

> But in this you have to use javascript for that.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```